# How to know the 'kivy' version I have installed in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, kivy

How to know the 'kivy' version currently got installed into my ubuntu 14.04 from command line?

Answer (score 1):

Type command `dpkg -s kivy`

```
Package: kivy
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: python
Installed-Size: 26
Maintainer: Thomas-Karl Pietrowski <thopiekar@googlemail.com>
Architecture: all
**Version: 1.9.0-3~stable0+201510211131~pkg77~ubuntu14.04.1**
```